# Wordpress Login Options

Tags: openid, wordpress, buddypress

I am building a BuddyPress site and have the OpenID and OpenID Selector plugins so that users can login that way.

I would like to force the users to use OpenID login and not the standard login.

Is there a way to do this without actually deleting the part of wp-login (and other areas) that asks for the username and password?

Thank you.

Comment: Post this at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ for better response.